# how to remove content from images when using multipart

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filestream, multipartform-data

so I made an uploader in my web API by using multipart form data but the problem is when I save my pictures from the file stream it also gave me the content here

```
 -----------------------------7e1e364095c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="C:\Users\kewin\Downloads\windows 10 pro.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

 the binary starts from here
```

and if i remove thoose 4 lines i can watch my picture so are there any way to remove that so I am only left with the picture

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadImage(string fileName = "")
    {
        if (fileName == "")
        {
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return BadRequest("Could not find file to upload");
        }
        var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());

        var files = provider.Files;
        var uploadedFile = files[0];
        var extension = ExtractExtension(uploadedFile);
        var contentType = uploadedFile.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        var savePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["savePath"];
        var file = string.Concat(savePath, fileName, extension);

        try
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var fileDir = file + request.Headers[""];
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileDir, FileMode.Create))
            {
                request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }

        try
        {
                var fileInfo = new UploadedFileInfo
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                FileExtension = extension,
                ContentType = contentType,
                FilePath = savePath + imageFile
            };
            return Ok(fileInfo);
        }
```

Comment: no. those are metadata so that you can access those in server such as file.FileName etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you read picture data from `request.InputStream`, which contains whole unparsed multipart content, including headers you don't need. Instead, you should read picture data from `InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` you created, which parses input stream and provides you simple access to headers and data stream of individual uploaded file(s).

```
....
var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());

var files = provider.Files;
var uploadedFile = files[0];
var extension = ExtractExtension(uploadedFile);
var contentType = uploadedFile.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
var savePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["savePath"];
var file = string.Concat(savePath, fileName, extension);

try
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
    return Ok();
}
....
```